# ASP.NET 4.5 doesn´t appear in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I already install the ASP.NET 4.5

But I can´t see it in IIS

I´m using Windows 2012 + IIS 8
I ran dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45

See here, please: i.stack.imgur.com/m1GQ5.png and here i.stack.imgur.com/PWc8h.png unhopful I can not to post images here yet. Thanks again

Any help??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Did you check the appPools in IIS?

Comment: IIS will list it as .NET 4.0. You can just upload your 4.5 site and see if it works.

Comment: You won't see the framework version in IIS - but you will see the CLR version.  CLR 2.0 covers framework 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5.  CLR 4.0 covers framework 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2.

Comment: I did. See here, please:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/m1GQ5.png 

and here 

http://i.stack.imgur.com/PWc8h.png

unhopful I can not to post images here yet.

Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure where the first screenshot is from - there's not enough context.  But the second screenshot clearly shows .NET CLR version 4.0.  The name of the App Pool doesn't guarantee it's 4.5 (it is a good bet).  You could name it whatever you desire - the fact remains that, at least from an IIS app pool perspective, it will be either 2.0 or 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Open your IIS Manager
In the Applicaiton Pools Node you will see a list of Application pools
Locate the pool your application is using and open it. (double click)
For example DefaultAppPool
Here you will see the version of the .net framework you are using.
For asp.net 4.5 I believe you will not see 4.5 but 4. xyz.. depending on the patch and etc..   Hope this helps
[image: IIS App Poll]

Comment: I did. See here, please:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/m1GQ5.png 

and here 

http://i.stack.imgur.com/PWc8h.png

unhopful I can not to post images here yet.

Thanks again.